# Locally finite p-group and commutator subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G/Z(G)$ be a locally finite $p$-group. I have to prove that $G'$ is a
locally finite $p$-group too. The hint is to use Schur theorem, but I can't figure out how to get something like a subgroup of finite index. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to prove that for any finite subset $S$ of $[G,G]$ (I don't like using $G'$ for the derived group), the subgroup $\langle S \rangle$ of $G$ generated by $S$ is a finite $p$-group.

Each element of $S$ is a product $[g_1,h_1][g_2,h_2]\cdots [g_n,h_n]$ of commutatos of elements of $G$. For each eleemnt of $S$. choose such a product, and let $T$ be the finite set consisting of all of the elements $g_i,h_i$ that occur in any of these expressions for the elements of $S$. Then clearly $\langle S \rangle \le [T,T]$.

Since $G/Z(G)$ is a locally finite $p$-group, $T/Z(T)$ is a finite $p$-group.  Schur's Theorem now says that $[T,T]$ is finite, and if you look at the proof you will see that it actually proves that it is finite of exponent dividing $|T/Z(T)|$. So $[T,T]$ is a finite $p$-group and hence so is $\langle S \rangle$.